# Difference between two different pandas columns

Tags: python-3.x, function, pandas, difference

I build a function for do a difference between two different pandas columns from different data set. First data set contain the predict value and the second data set contain observed. The problem is that the row of two data set are different and for do a difference I  must use the ID of row.

The function is:

```
def difference(data1,data2):              
    for i in range(data1.shape[0]):
        e_id=data2.iloc[i,0]
        p_oss =data1.iloc[int(e_id),9]
        diff= p_oss - data2.iloc[i,1]
    return diff

difference(df,evaluation)
```

Where: data1: observed value data2:predict value

The error of functionis:

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

The observed data set is structured like this:

```
ID Attribute1 Attribute2 ... Prime
1     N         10            123
2     S         10            128
3     N          8             26
4     S         12            567
..
n     N         15             5
```

The predict data set is structured like this:

```
ID   Prime
4     566.89
1     123.03
2     127.95
3     26.01
...
```

The ID of predict data set change because I use a function (`train_test_split`) to split the originally df in train e test set.

I want an output like this:

```
ID   difference
1      0.03
2      0.05
3      0.1
4      0.11
```

..

Comment: Do you mind to edit with an example of the two dataframes and the output you're looking for?

Comment: what's wrong with `(observed_df['Prime'] - predict_df['Prime']).abs()`

Comment: just using `-` and `abs()` works if `ID` is the index.

Comment: I can't use 'observed_df['Prime'] - predict_df['Prime']' because  the two df are different index